# TimerCallback not returning value C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, callback, return

I am using `System.Threading.Timer` to create a timer that prints a string to a serial port and then  reads from another serial port every second. I am trying to do this by sending arguments to my `TimerCallback` function. Below is my code where the timer is initialized and the code for the callback function.

Initialization:

```
TimerCallback tcb = Timer_func(buff_out, send_port, recv_port);
AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
Timer aTimer = new Timer(tcb,autoEvent,1000,1000);
```

Callback function:

```
public static TimerCallback Timer_func(string buff_out, SerialPort send_port, SerialPort recv_port)
{
    string buff_in;
    send_port.WriteLine(buff_out);
    buff_in = recv_port.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(buff_in);
}
```

The initialization occurs in the Main() function, and both functions are in the same class.

When I compile the code as is I recieve error CS0161: "not all code paths return a value". In attempts to remedy this I've added `return 1;` to the end of that function but then I recieve error CS0029: "cannot explicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Threading.Timer'.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it. (New to C#). Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are quite lost with this code.  There are no scenario where you can make this reliable with a Timer.  You've got some code somewhere else that sets *buff_out*.  Have that code also call SerialPort.WriteLine() + ReadLine().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misunderstanding delegates.

[`TimerCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timercallback.aspx) is a *delegate type* – a type that can hold a function.
`TimerCallback` can only hold functions with the signature

```
void MethodName(Object state)
```

When you write

```
public static TimerCallback Timer_func(...) { ... }
```

You just declared a function that *returns* a `TimerCallback` delegate.
Thus, your function must return a function that matches TimerCallback.

You can do that using an anonymous delegate:

```
return delegate (object state) {
    string buff_in;
    send_port.WriteLine(buff_out);
    buff_in = recv_port.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(buff_in);
};
```

Comment: can the delegate take more arguments than `object state`? Because send_port, recv_port, and buff_out are all declared in the main() function and are not in the scope of the delegate function.

Comment: @dtemps123: No; `Timer` wouldn't know what to pass it.  Instead, declare the anonymous delegate directly inside `Main()` (and get rid of your function) and it will be able to access them via closure.  Or, make them fields in the class.